# Custom HTML for the search box used by the ListController behavior

Tags: php, octobercms

I want to customize list searching behavior for backend panel.

[image]

I need to send keywords through ajax request, make a specific query and return/update this list.

At the moment search input works through [Data attributes API](https://octobercms.com/docs/ajax/attributes-api).

```
<input placeholder="Search..." type="text" name="listToolbarSearch[term]" value="2" data-request="listToolbarSearch::onSubmit" data-track-input="" data-load-indicator="" data-load-indicator-opaque="" class="form-control icon search growable" autocomplete="off">
```

To be more exact I want to extend `data-request="listToolbarSearch::onSubmit"` function or make something like this and execute it through [javascript ajax api](https://octobercms.com/docs/ajax/javascript-api) on click event. I can't find this function in the framework(

Answer (score 6):

This is fairly simple to do. Inside your List Controller configuration (`config_list.yaml` file), the toolbar search option will accept a partial name to use.

```
# Toolbar widget configuration
toolbar:
    # Partial for toolbar buttons
    buttons: list_toolbar

    # Partial for toolbar search
    search: my_search
```

Then inside your controller view directory you can use any search markup you like. For example, create a partial called `_my_search.htm` with these contents:

```
<div class="loading-indicator-container size-input-text">
    <input
        placeholder="Search for something"
        type="text"
        name="term"
        value=""
        data-request="onMyHandler"
        data-track-input
        data-load-indicator
        data-load-indicator-opaque
        class="form-control"
        autocomplete="off" />
</div>
```